# Making $x^n$ in Pascal's Trangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Label the n th diagonal $a^n$.
(For example,$1,3,6,10,15...$ will be labeled $a^3$.)

Let $p$ be a integer,and try to add or subtract lists of $a^n$ to get a series like below:
The first term is $1$, then the second term is $2^p$, and term $n$ is $n^p$.
(For example,when $p$ is 2, you get the squares($1,4,9,16$),and can be expressed as $2×a^3-a^2$.)

Can we find a gereral form of expression that expresses the series?

(I also find that  when $p$ is 3, it is made of $6a^4-6a^3+a^2$.)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. See Stirling numbers of the second kind. Namely, $x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n S_2(n,k)k!\binom xk$.

Comment: What is S2? I don't understand. Also, why is the formula true?Is there a proof?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind. There is a reference for the proof of the identity

Comment: Possibly typo in the 1st paragraph.  In the sequence $~\binom{2}{2}, \binom{3}{2}, \binom{4}{2}, \cdots~$ it looks like the $~\color{red}{19}~$ entry should be $~10.$

Comment: Please use new notation that does not conflict with existing ones. The notation $a^n$ already means the product of $n$ copies of $a$ (exponentiation), so it should not be used to mean something different.

Comment: Re the comment of @GeoffreyTrang, you can substitute $~a_n~$ for $~a^n,~$ since $~a_n~$ does not have any pre-defined meaning.